# Tensorflow GO - how to port python querie

Tags: python, tensorflow, go

pretty new to the whole world of tf and co.

managed to create/train/predict a model - in jupyter-playbook using python.

for production, i'd like to use golang. but i am unable to find a "simple" sample on how to do the prediction inside go.

i'd like to have this piece of python, for go:

```
sample = {
    'b': 200,
    'c': 10,
    'd': 1,
}

input_dict = {name: tf.convert_to_tensor([value]) for name, value in sample.items()}
predictions = reloaded_model.predict(input_dict)
prob = tf.nn.sigmoid(predictions[0])
```

anyone has a good tutorial for `model.Session.Run`  using github.com/galeone/tensorflow/tensorflow/go

regards
helmut

Answer (score 0):

ok so i managed todo it, so i answer it myself for other folks!
using tfgo

```golang
import (
  tf "github.com/galeone/tensorflow/tensorflow/go"
  tg "github.com/galeone/tfgo"
)

func main() {
  model := tg.LoadModel("../krot-classifier", []string{"serve"}, nil)
  start := time.Now()
  fakeInput, _ := tf.NewTensor([][]float32{{1}})
  //fakeString, _ := tf.NewTensor([][]string{{"127.0.0"}})
  results := model.Exec([]tf.Output{
    model.Op("StatefulPartitionedCall", 0),
  }, map[tf.Output]*tf.Tensor{
    model.Op("serving_default_b", 0): fakeInput,
    model.Op("serving_default_c", 0): fakeInput,
    model.Op("serving_default_d", 0): fakeInput,
  })
    predictions := results[0]
    pred := predictions.Value().([][]float32)
    prob := sigmoid(float64(pred[0][0]))
    fmt.Printf("%.1f percent probability\n", (100 * prob))

}
func sigmoid(x float64) float64 {
    return 1 / (1 + math.Exp(x*(-1)))
}
```

for string inputs see the `fakeString`